# What does the Weight of Darkness effect do?

Tags: destiny

I've seen some YouTube videos of people doing raids where they get an effect called **Weight of Darkness**.

What does it do and what happens when it's multiplied (ex. Weight of Darkness x5)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first zone of the Crota raid, every second or so you will gain 1 stack of Weight of Darkness. It does not cause any damage and there is no associated death timer or damage timer.

Your speed is diminished with each stack, the first stack prevents you from jumping a second time in the air. You can still run, although not max speed, until you have 10 stacks at which point you may only walk. At any point you can still jump once.

There are only 4 ways of getting rid of the stacks.

- Dying
- Completing the zone
- By standing on one of two pads, the one you load on, and a similar one after all 16 "lamps"
- By standing near a lamp, but beware, they will explode after a short time about 20 seconds.

When on a pad or near a lamp you lose a stack at the same rate you gain them.

Answer (score 7):

From the [wiki](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Crota%27s_End):

> Weight of Darkness, which can stack up to 10 times. It disables the ability to double-jump and reduces movement speed. Weight of Darkness can only be removed by standing close to one of the lighted pillars.

Courtesy of turbo - It is a good tip to note that the Blade Dancer's ability "Arc Blade" removes the effect while the ability is active; and the Sun Singer's ability "Fireborn" also resets this as well.

Comment: note that blade dancing as a hunter temporarily removes the effects of weight of darkness, and self reviving as a sunsinger resets the effects of weight of darkness.